# "Jacobian" of a matrix-valued function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

If a matrix $Y$ of dimensions $(m,h)$ is defined as the product of matrices $X(m,x)$ and $W(x,h)$,$Y = X \cdot W$, how do I obtain the partial derivative of $Y$ with respect to $W$? 
I need this derivative as part of the chain rule to eventually calculate the derivative of a scalar C with respect to $W$

$Y$=$X$*$W$

$output$=$row-$$wise$ $softmax$($Y$)

$CE$=-$label$ $\circ$ $log(output)$    ie element-wise multiplication

$C=$ $1/m\sum_{i,j} CE_{i,j}$ where m = number of rows in CE

Dimensions :

$X=$($m*x$)

$W=$($x*h$)

$Y,output,label=$($m*h$)

$C =scalar$

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I need to compute gradients for backpropagating errors in a neural network

Comment: You are probably not actually interested in this gradient (which by the way is a 4th order tensor, not a matrix).  But rather, you are attempting to apply the chain rule, and it requires this quantity as an intermediate value in the overall calculation.  My advice is to forget about the chain rule and approach the problem some other way, e.g. using differentials.

Comment: Greg, that is right. I need to calculate (eventually) the derivative of a scalar wrt W for which i was using the chain rule.

Comment: Okay, add the definition of the scalar to the question. The gradient of a scalar wrt a matrix is simply a matrix with the same dimensions. There's no need to fool around with 4th order tensors to solve the problem.

Comment: @greg I have edited the question and provided the definition of the scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Since you evaluate the output function over rows, there's no need to deal with the matrix as a whole. You can write $Y=XW$ in row-wise form as
$$y_k^T=x_k^TW \implies y_k=W^Tx_k$$
For now, let's drop the $k$ subscript and workout the gradient for a single row. Then at the end, we'll sum over all the rows.

Let's use (:) to represent the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$

and write down the variables and their differentials
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\b{\beta}
 y &= W^Tx &\implies dy = dW^Tx \\
 s &= {\rm softmax}(y) \\
 S &= {\rm Diag}(s) &\implies ds = (S-ss^T)dy  \\
 \phi &= -b:\log(s) \\
 \b &= s:b = s^Tb \\
}$$
Now find the differential and gradient of the $\phi$ function.
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= -b:S^{-1}ds \\
 &= -b:(I-\o s^T)dy \\
 &= (\b \o -b):dy \\
 &= (\b \o -b):dW^Tx \\
 &= (\b \o -b)x^T:dW^T \\
 &= x(\b \o -b)^T:dW \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= x(\b \o -b)^T \\
}$$
That's the gradient for a single row. To find the full gradient, sum over all the rows
$$\eqalign{
\Phi &= \frac{\o }{m}\sum_k \phi_k \\
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial W}
 &= \frac{\o }{m}\sum_k \frac{\partial\phi_k}{\partial W} \\
 &= \frac{\o }{m}\sum_k x_k(\b-b_k)^T \\
}$$
When working through these expressions, it helps to know that the Frobenius product is commutative.
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= B:A \\
}$$
It is also useful to know the rules for rearranging a Frobenius product, which follow from the cyclic properties of the trace.
$$\eqalign{
 A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
\\
}$$

---

Here is a quick derivation of the gradient of the softmax
$$\eqalign{
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\h{\odot}
 a &= \exp(z) &\implies da = a\h dz \\
 A &= {\rm Diag}(a) \\
 \a &= \o :a = \o^Ta &\implies d\a = \o :da \\
 y &= {\rm softmax}(z)=\frac{a}{\a} \\
 Y &= {\rm Diag}(y) &\implies Y=\frac{A}{\a} \\
\\
dy
 &= \frac{\a\,da-a\,d\a}{\a^2} \\
 &= \frac{\a\,a\h dz-a\,\o :da}{\a^2} \\
 &= \frac{\a\,a\h dz-a\,(\o :a\h dz)}{\a^2} \\
 &= \frac{\a A\,dz-a\,(a:dz)}{\a^2} \\
 &= \frac{(\a A-aa^T)\,dz}{\a^2} \\
 &= (Y-yy^T)\,dz \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks @greg .How was the derivative of the softmax arrived at?

Comment: Also, could you please recommend a book, online course or anything ,really ,that I could use to study matrix calculus?

Comment: I had to re-work the whole problem because I mistakenly used the logistic (sigmoid) function instead of the softmax.